# capture image doesnt display in imageview

Tags: android

im doing a simple android camera application that capture one picture then display it. the capturing part is working however i cant display it on the imageview.there wasnt any error but in one of the logcat stated this

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3120x4208, max=4096x4096)
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getfile();
                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent,CAM_REQUEST);

            }
        });
    }

    private File getfile(){

        File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");

        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File image_file = new File (folder, "cam_image.jpg");
        return image_file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lala.camera.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture Image"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.amirul.camera">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is too large you have to resize it.
Try this:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(resize(Drawable.createFromPath(path)));

private Drawable resize(Drawable image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);
}
```

Comment: thanks it works great. didnt know that i had to resize the image